# Check if LAS overlaps shapefile

Tags: r, lidr

I want to check if the extent of a LAS file overlap any polygon in a shapefile:

```
library(lidR)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(sp)

f = "D:/Skapa_DEM/inputs/19D021_67000_5250_25.laz"

las <- readLAS(f)
lasextent = extent(las)
xmin = lasextent[1]
xmax = lasextent[2]
ymin = lasextent[3]
ymax = lasextent[4]

e <- as(raster::extent(ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax), "SpatialPolygons")
proj4string(e) <- "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"
df <- readOGR("D:/Skapa_DEM/testarea.shp")
```

I've tried:

```
#st_intersection(e, df)
#Error in UseMethod("st_intersection") : 
#  no applicable method for 'st_intersection' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial', 'SpatialVector')"

#intersect(df, e)
#Error in as.vector(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

But it does not work, see errors. There must be some easier way. How?

Comment: well, your error refers to `st_intersection` being created for class `sf` (from package `sf`)  and you are using it on `sp` objects, you may use `sf::st_as_sf()` to convert your `sp` objects and then just try `st_intersects` (which just returns a logical) of `st_intersection` if you do need the area extent of the intersection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use functions from the `sf` package for this.

First, get the LAS extent as an sf polygon (I'm using the output from help(readLAS) here):

```
> las_extent = st_as_sfc(st_bbox(las))
```

Then if you have `sf` polygons with the right CRS:

```
> pols
Geometry set for 3 features 
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 684733.5 ymin: 5017723 xmax: 684937.2 ymax: 5017947
Projected CRS: NAD83 / UTM zone 17N
POLYGON ((684733.9 5017744, 684738.3 5017772, 6...
POLYGON ((684797 5017926, 684812.9 5017883, 684...
POLYGON ((684881.7 5017937, 684880 5017891, 684...
```

you can use `st_intersects` to test intersection:

```
> st_intersects(pols, las_extent)
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 3, where the predicate
was `intersects'
 1: (empty)
 2: 1
 3: 1
```

This shows my first polygon doesn't intersect the LAS boundary but the other two do.

```
> plot(las_extent, lwd=2, col="grey")
> plot(pols, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Grey is my LAS extent, the first polygon is bottom left. The other two intersect.

Doing the test this way you can test the length of each intersection vector using `lengths` to get a boolean test of intersection:

```
> lengths(st_intersects(pols, las_extent)) > 0
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```